# Sencha Touch tutorials or examples for RSS Feeds in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, sencha-touch, extjs

I am a newbie in building Sencha Touch with Ruby on Rails. I would like to have some good examples of Sencha Touch for Building RSS Feeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't use Sencha for the RSS feeds, it's would just be standard Rails code.